# Stored Procedure not fired properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am calling a stored procedure as usual in the following way

```
public void runSP(int Id){
    using(var context = new Entities())
    {
        SqlParameter IdParam = new SqlParameter("@id", Id);
        var x = context.Database.SqlQuery<entity>("sp_ChosenSP @id", IdParam);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

The Stored Procedure takes the `Id` and deletes that from `entity`. The thing now is that this `Id` only seems to be deleted when I am in debug view and set a Breakpoint at `savechanges` and then open the Results View for x (hover over x, click the arrow down and open Results View).

So my question is, why is this happening and how should I adapt my code make it right?
Thanks!

Comment: Did you test first your stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio to see if it works? You do something like: EXEC sp_ChosenSP 3

Comment: Please add error/exception handling and also capture the result of the SaveChanges call

Comment: @Alexandru-DanPop: yes, I have tested the SP and it works fine.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: The original code does have error handling, but an exception is not triggered.

Comment: So simple really! This shows I have quite something to learn about Sql etc. Thanks for your help. This fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database.SqlQuery should be used to retrieve rows, not to delete them.

Use ExecuteSqlCommand to call an Update or Delete procedure.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
public void runSP(int Id){
    using(var context = new Entities())
    {
        SqlParameter idParam = new SqlParameter("@id", Id);
        var x = context.Database.SqlQuery<entity>("exec sp_ChosenSP @id", idParam ).ToList<entity>();
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```